# Validating SQLAlchemy enum before a save operaiton

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Consider the following column definition:

```
group_name = db.Column(db.Enum('dogs', 'cats', name='device_group'))
```

Then in my API function I do:

```
lassie.group_name = userData.group
db.session.add(obj)
db.session.commit()
```

The problem that even if `userData.group` is treated as string in Python. Even if its value is `"bird"`, until I actually do the commit operation, I will get no exception.

- Why is SQLAlchemy is treating `group_name` as a string and not an enum?
- How can I validate that the value I am putting on the object is an enum?
- Should I perhaps use [SQLAlchemy validator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_attributes.html) for that?

Comment: what happens when you use `@validates('group_name')`?

Comment: @LawrenceBenson How do you mean? Writing a custom validator?

Comment: @VitalyB What was the solution for this?

Comment: @KavinRajuS I'm afraid I found none. The best way was to manually verify the enjm values on read and write.

Comment: Oh okay cool.... Thank you @VitalyB